# jss nested camelCase classes are converted to kebab-case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I'm trying to force JSS to always use camelCase, including nested styles.

So If I have these styles:

```
jss.use(camelCase(), nested(), cssGlobal(), defaultUnit());
export const stylesObject = jss.createStyleSheet(
  {
    parentContainer: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      position: 'relative',

     '& .childWrapper': {
          ...
      }
    },
}
```

The compiled CSS outcome from this is like this:

```
.parentContainer {
   ....
}

.parentContainer .child-wrapper {
   ...
}
```

What I want is all to be camelCase, so it would be:

```
.parentContainer .childWrapper {
   ...
}
```

How can I achieve this? Do I have to manually iterate through the styles before doing an `attach()` and change kebab-case to camelCase? I was wondering if there was any other "official" way to do it.

Thanks in advance.